# Не могу понять почему не выводится текст

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myString
{
    char* string;
    int length;
public:
    myString(char* t_string);
    void showString();
};
myString::myString(char* t_string)
{
    string=new char[5];
    while(*t_string)
    {
        *string++=*t_string++;
    }
}
void myString::showString()
{
    while(*string++)
    {
        cout<<*string;
    }
}
            
int main()
{
    myString string("Hello");
    string.showString();
    return 0;
}
```

После компиляции и запуска ничего не выводит

Comment: вы в конструкторе сразу изменили личную переменную `string` на конец строки и она уже указывает в пустоту. *памяти надо больше : 5 букв + 1 байт конца строки '\00'*

Comment: "Не могу понять..." это не вопрос, а нытье.  Старайтесь оформлять вопрос грамотней

Answer (score 5):

"Да понять-то его, надёжа-государь, немудрено" (с):

```
myString::myString(char* t_string)
{
    string=new char[5];
    while(*t_string)
    {
        *string++=*t_string++;
    }
}
```

Куда после этого указывает `string`? Правильно, *за конец* реальной строки. Кстати, это ведет еще и к утечке памяти, но это второй вопрос...

И **что** теперь должен выводить этот код?

```
void myString::showString()
{
    while(*string++)
    {
        cout<<*string;
    }
}
```

Помните, куда указывает `string`? Вот так и получается *неопределенное поведение*...

**Update**

Вот код более-менее нормального класса без утечек...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myString
{
    char* s;
public:
    myString(const char* t);
    myString(const myString& m)
        :myString(m.s){};
    myString& operator=(myString m)
    {
        char * t = s;
        s = m.s;
        m.s = t;
        return *this;
    }
    void showString();
    ~myString() { delete[] s; }
};

myString::myString(const char* t)
:s(new char[strlen(t)+1])
{
    char * q = s;
    while(*q++ = *t++);
    // Проще strcpy(s,t);
}

void myString::showString()
{
    char * q = s;
    while(*q)
    {
        cout<<*q++;
    }
    // Проще cout << s;
}

int main()
{
    myString s("Hello");
    s.showString();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: простите за мою тупость,я примерно понял о чём вы мне говорите но не могли бы вы разжевать мне посильнее пожалуйста,или подсказать в каком направлении рыть чтобы понять этот вопрос лучше

Comment: Использовать переменную для работы, а исходную оставить в классе нетронутой...

Comment: Утечки памяти в примере не было, т.к. строчка статическая. Но тут куча вопросов, например, как вообще `const char*` созданный выражением `"Hello"` присвоился `char*`у

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `string=new char[5];` Это вы называете статической строчкой? (Строка 13 в коде в тексте вопроса.) Соответствующего оператора `delete[]` в том же коде нет (да если бы и был — значение указателя оказывается утеряно.). Если это не утечка, то что тогда утечка?

Comment: @Harry Хм, странно. 4 раза перечитывал текст и не видел new ** *ушел за кофе*

Answer (score 1):

Вы двигает указатель на строку, после того как вы запускаете вывод он уже указывает за строку.

Вообще там не всегда пустой вывод, просто так повезло, вообще можно поймать мусор если несколько раз попробовать.(MVS)

Если откроете в дебагере Visual Studio, там четко и пошагово все видно

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myString
{
    int length;
    char* string;
public:
    myString(const char* t_string);
    void showString();
};
myString::myString(const char* t_string)
{
    string = new char[strlen(t_string)];
    char* ptr_start = string;
    do
    {
        *ptr_start++ = *t_string++;
    } while (*ptr_start != '\0');

}
void myString::showString()
{
    char* ptr = string;
    do
    {
        std::cout << *(ptr++);
    } while (*ptr != '\0');
}

int main()
{
    myString string("Hello");
    string.showString();
    return 0;
}
```

Можно и без указателей сделать

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myString
{
    size_t length;
    char* string;
public:
    template<size_t N>
    myString(const char(&t_string)[N])
        : length(N)
    {
        string = new char[length];
        strcpy_s(string,length, t_string);
    };
    void showString()
    {
        std::cout << string;
    }
};
int main()
{
    myString str("hello");
    str.showString();
    return 0;
}
```